# Which items cannot be smelted in neither the smoker nor the blast furnace?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

1.14 saw the addition of smokers and blast furnaces to Minecraft. Their main purpose is to speed up the smelting of certain items. Smokers are for smelting food, and blast furnaces are for non-food items. Right?

Apparently, I was wrong.

I just tried to smelt sand to make it into glass. It wasn't a food item, and I put it in the blast furnace. It wasn't accepted.

I then thought maybe that it was considered a smoker item, not a blast furnace item. So I decided to put it into the smoker and test it.

It *also* wasn't accepted.

Therefore, it must be that some items cannot be smelted in either special furnace, and must be smelted using the normal furnace.

I now know that Sand → Glass is a recipe that must be used in a regular furnace, and not a smoker/blast furnace.

The Minecraft Wiki doesn't provide a full list of these items, only saying that "some items" are not compatible with either furnace.

To save me from having to enter the maintenance area of my *Smoker & Blast Furnace Super Smelter™* and pluck out items that don't belong, could someone provide a full list of these items?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Items that may be used in a smoker

Raw food items only. Notable exception is Chorus Fruit; although it is edible, it cannot be cooked in a smoker because its smelting product (Popped Chorus Fruit) is not edible.

- Raw Porkchop → Cooked Porkchop
- Raw Beef → Steak
- Raw Chicken → Cooked Chicken
- Raw Cod → Cooked Cod
- Raw Salmon → Cooked Salmon
- Potato → Baked Potato
- Raw Mutton → Cooked Mutton
- Raw Rabbit → Cooked Rabbit
- Kelp → Dried Kelp

## Items that may be used in a blast furnace

Ores of any type, Chain/Iron/Gold armor and tools, and Ancient debris only. Note that block types cannot be smelted in a blast furnace—you will only get ore items from the blast furnace (nuggets, iron, etc).

- Ancient Debris → Netherite Scrap
- Gold Ore → Gold Ingot
- Iron Ore → Iron Ingot
- Diamond Ore → Diamond
- Lapis Lazuli Ore → Lapis Lazuli
- Redstone Ore → Redstone Dust
- Coal Ore → Coal
- Emerald Ore → Emerald
- Nether Gold Ore → Gold Ingot
- Nether Quartz Ore → Nether Quartz
- Chain/Iron/Gold Armor → Iron/Gold Nugget
- Iron tools → Iron Nugget

## Items that may be only used in a furnace

The furnace may be used to smelt any of the items in the other sections. However, ONLY the furnace may be used to smelt these items:

- Sand → Glass
- Cobblestone → Stone
- Sandstone → Smooth Sandstone
- Red Sandstone → Smooth Red Sandstone
- Stone → Smooth Stone
- Block of Quartz → Smooth Quartz
- Clay Ball → Brick
- Netherrack → Nether Brick
- Nether Bricks → Cracked Nether Bricks
- Clay → Terracotta
- Stone Bricks → Cracked Stone Bricks
- Dyed Terracotta → Glazed Terracotta
- Log/Stripped Log → Charcoal
- Wood/Stripped Wood → Charcoal
- Chorus Fruit → Popped Chorus Fruit
- Wet Sponge → Sponge
- Sea Pickle → Lime Dye
- Cactus → Green Dye

## Sources

- Minecraft Wiki:

  - [Smelting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Smelting)
  - [Smoker](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Smoker)
  - [Blast Furnace](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Blast_Furnace)

Comment: This is only in furnace:
Cactus -> Green dye